# Duplicate Web Service call using Jersey client

Tags: web-services, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

We have been facing issue with the Jersey client (ver 1.8) ends up making duplicate service call even though the system is requesting for just one.

1. System makes a web service call through Jersey client
2. Web Service provider ends up getting two calls.
3. In our logs we get only one request and response logs
4. While update calls even though we sends one request but Jersey client makes 2 calls to the web service provider but we get response back from only the second call which always gives us a Duplicate record error.

Comment: did you figure this out? have observed the same behaviour and curious if there's a bug report for it.

Comment: I have the same issue on Jersey 2.23.2.